# Mercurial support in QtCreator 2.5.0 in Linux

Tags: mercurial, qt-creator

There seems to be Mercurial support build into QtCreator 2.5.0 in Linux, I can run commands like hg status, annotate, whatnot directly from QtCreator.

How can I, however, make QtCreator display status of a file in the Project tree (like all the Java IDE's used to do with Subversion when I used them a few years ago)?

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator currently have no such feature in any VCS plugin. You can fire feature request to https://bugreports.qt-project.org/